# Different installation requirements for normal bolts vs torque-to-yield bolts

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, bolting

Why do stretch bolts need to be rotated 90 or 180 degrees after being torqued to a specified value? Why not just torque it to 120 nM instead of 100 nM + 90 degrees of rotation?

Also would it be possible to replace torque-to-yield bolts with normal bolts for head gaskets for instance?

Comment: Could be a measurement problem in that the acceptable yield range is too small or variable to be determined by torque measurements and instead needs to be determined by displacement.

Comment: What causes the variability in yield range? Wouldn't it also affect displacement?

Comment: What is nM? If n is meant to be newtons then N.

Comment: the wiki article on torque-to-yield bolts explains their use

Comment: I was just throwing the idea out there but I looked into it more and I am pretty sure it is correct.

Comment: the symbol for metre is `m`

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure it is because once the bolt begins to yield and enters the plastic range, the stress (i.e. force or torque) is no longer an accurate indicator of the strain (deformation) experienced by the bolt.

A regular bolt experiences deformation due to tightening only in the elastic region and never enters the plastic region, but the final tightening of a torque-to-yield bolt does.

If you look at stress-vs strain curves, the shape of the curve changes quite a bit when you enter the plastic region. One of the most prominent changes is that slope shallows out a lot. This means that in the plastic range you lose "sensitivity" so to speak when trying to use stress as an indication of strain. If the slope flattens out completely then that means the stress no longer changes at all in response to the strain. And that's not even the worst case. You can see from the example graphs that the curve actually loses monotonicity.

[image]

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Stress-Strain-curve-for-an-elastic-material-Within-the-elastic-region-if-the-material_fig27_305728176

[image]
https://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=kts&NM=280

Answer (score 0):

Torque plus turn systems and torque to yield hardware are two totally separate things. You can have one, the other, or both.

The relationship between applied torque and the actual bolt tension that results is *very* approximate. Under optimal conditions using the highest quality threads and best quality control practices, like in aircraft production, the variation might be 20% among a set of bolts, and the mean value might be out by 10-15% from the target value using the best calibrated torque wrenches available (they cost thousands of dollars). In more "agricultural" settings, variation using a standard torque wrench on common hardware without lubrication or calibration and without much surface prep could easily be 40%. This is for new nuts and bolts. Reusing hardware is a total crap shoot. Where higher consistency is wanted, and engine head bolts for high performance engines is a good example, torque-plus-turn systems are preferable when done right. But you have to make certain that the initial torqueing is sufficient bed the faying surfaces completely. For it to be effective, we are talking about ground and lapped mating parts, and all the correct thread lubricants on QC tested new hardware, with part control on every nut, bolt, and washer in the system. Those things are where most of the consistency comes from. Otherwise, you can expect about the same results as a what you get from a yard ape with a box wrench and a modicum of experience.

Torque-plus-turn systems are also used on gasketed systems where the gasket is relatively soft and you want an accurate squeeze to make the seal. Hydraulic fittings with O-ring face seals might be specified as finger tight plus two flats. Head gaskets need to be crushed just the right amount without warping things. Fuel injectors with crush washer seals need the proper amount of squeeze. Even a spin-on oil filter works this way. But none of this has anything to do with torque-to-yield bolts. There are still a lot of head bolts out there that use torque plus turn sequences but are not TTY.

Torque to yield bolts were developed to solve a couple specific problems that began showing up on engines with aluminum heads and cast iron blocks. The aluminum expands more and caused fretting on the head gaskets under shear, and the head bolts often failed due to fatigue as the preload went away. The first fix was to redesign the head gaskets. But they still needed a more tolerant bolt that would accommodate thermal expansion differences without suffering fatigue failures. And getting the multi-layered gaskets to work properly requires better control of the squeeze.

Normal bolts won't do the job. Firstly, a normal (whatever that means) grade 8 bolt from a reputable MFG that can trace and verify the source is still nowhere near the quality of an OEM head bolt. Grade 8 is just the beginning where engineering enters the picture. Head bolts have the threads rolled *after* heat treatment, and then they need a special aftertreatment and tempering at just the right temps to retain properties. Head bolts are often exposed to the coolant gallery, so they need sealants and coatings. The coatings are prone to trap hydrogen that promotes fatigue failures, so the coatings have to be just porous enough that you can bake the hydrogen out of them without tempering the bolts. Done right, they will have more than ten times the cycle endurance limit of a grade 8 bolt with cut threads.

Do you even know the thread profile and class fit of your head bolts?

[https://www.sae.org/publications/technical-papers/content/2003-01-3657/#:~:text=An%20increase%20in%20the%20fatigue,formation%20of%20the%20threaded%20fillets](https://www.sae.org/publications/technical-papers/content/2003-01-3657/#:%7E:text=An%20increase%20in%20the%20fatigue,formation%20of%20the%20threaded%20fillets).

https://www.sae.org/publications/technical-papers/content/2005-01-1321/

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer.